# Querying the "Annoy" index for all the points within radius r

Tags: python, algorithm, nearest-neighbor, annoy

Can I use spotify's "Annoy" package to query points within radius r

```
https://github.com/tjrileywisc/annoy
```

I coudn't find any relevant function call in the implementation on their github page.

I have used Kd-tree using query ball point for such problem. But since annoy is faster and I have to query billions of points, I am wondering if its possible to using this package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I use spotify's "Annoy" package to query points within radius r?

No, the library doesn't provide such a method.